# Make the picture act as a link from actionlink

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

Goal:
Make the candy picture as a link that the user can press them.

Problem:
I don't know how to do it based on the code below.

Info:
*Please remember that the link is a actionlink from asp.net mvc.
*Please remember that it is the candy picture should be the link, not the text.
*Dont forget to make the page into a full screen after you have pressed the "Run the snippet"

```css
p {
    font-size: 24px;
}

#foo {
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    display:block;
    top:400px;
    width:128px;
    height:128px;
    background: #f00 url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/uiconstock/50-free-christmas/128/candy-2-icon.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
  
  

}

#fooo {
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    display:block;
    top:400px;
    width:128px;
    height:128px;
    background: #f00 url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/uiconstock/50-free-christmas/128/candy-2-icon.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
  

}
```

```html
  
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut varius sagittis tincidunt. Donec consectetur sem vitae lorem finibus dictum. Pellentesque cursus sollicitudin eros vitae ullamcorper. Praesent consectetur posuere metus vel dictum. Mauris vitae fringilla libero. Fusce dui leo, bibendum a porttitor ullamcorper, scelerisque vitae quam. Praesent laoreet magna nisi, sit amet luctus quam condimentum vel. Phasellus aliquam nec sem sed eleifend. Donec hendrerit semper efficitur. Sed malesuada nisi quis arcu accumsan tincidunt. Mauris rutrum nisl lorem, a ullamcorper massa pharetra at. Pellentesque et risus sit amet massa finibus consequat eget vitae nibh.</p>

<p>Ut dapibus aliquet imperdiet. Maecenas gravida sagittis eros, nec vestibulum lacus sagittis at. Nulla enim dui, ultricies a quam id, placerat placerat erat. Donec pretium orci purus, eget tristique neque mattis eget. Nullam mattis accumsan urna et faucibus. Praesent tincidunt lobortis tortor, maximus tincidunt neque cursus luctus. Sed in rutrum lacus. Nunc volutpat fringilla diam. Curabitur accumsan, est sed mattis ultricies, augue quam suscipit nisi, sit amet lobortis erat lorem in nunc. Nullam sagittis vulputate placerat. Nullam fringilla arcu id purus pretium, sed fringilla ligula aliquam.</p>

<p>Morbi quis mauris condimentum, accumsan nunc ac, porttitor nibh. Pellentesque maximus dolor nisi, eget bibendum nibh feugiat mollis. Donec lacinia turpis vulputate, viverra sapien in, aliquam metus. Etiam posuere, urna at dapibus placerat, lacus dolor imperdiet lorem, sit amet efficitur ante dui efficitur est. Cras quis tincidunt sapien. Fusce sit amet ultricies mauris. Mauris sit amet faucibus velit. Pellentesque non leo ante.</p>

<p>Sed eget lacus sodales, porttitor justo non, ornare magna. Phasellus pulvinar porta eros eget ultricies. Aliquam ante lectus, ultricies vel iaculis nec, posuere quis sapien. Praesent nisi purus, fermentum nec tortor sagittis, efficitur consectetur ipsum. Vivamus condimentum velit sed dictum fringilla. Mauris eu vulputate neque, eu ornare justo. Ut iaculis et libero nec lobortis. Quisque euismod quam felis, sed imperdiet enim feugiat fermentum. In viverra turpis molestie luctus elementum. Vestibulum quis vulputate massa. Praesent convallis congue dolor nec ornare. Aliquam lobortis est vitae lorem tempor viverra.</p>

<p>Duis commodo congue porttitor. Aenean nunc arcu, ultricies semper cursus a, euismod eget orci. Etiam tempus aliquam nisl non tristique. Fusce lobortis sagittis enim, id mattis magna semper congue. Nulla ornare venenatis ante, hendrerit sagittis dolor ultricies nec. Praesent varius sit amet odio quis lobortis. Praesent quis egestas sem, eget dignissim felis. Pellentesque risus enim, viverra a blandit in, laoreet sed quam. Duis et congue risus, sed consequat massa. Nunc non pharetra tortor. Morbi elementum magna vitae rutrum pulvinar. Donec sit amet leo arcu.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut varius sagittis tincidunt. Donec consectetur sem vitae lorem finibus dictum. Pellentesque cursus sollicitudin eros vitae ullamcorper. Praesent consectetur posuere metus vel dictum. Mauris vitae fringilla libero. Fusce dui leo, bibendum a porttitor ullamcorper, scelerisque vitae quam. Praesent laoreet magna nisi, sit amet luctus quam condimentum vel. Phasellus aliquam nec sem sed eleifend. Donec hendrerit semper efficitur. Sed malesuada nisi quis arcu accumsan tincidunt. Mauris rutrum nisl lorem, a ullamcorper massa pharetra at. Pellentesque et risus sit amet massa finibus consequat eget vitae nibh.</p>

  
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut varius sagittis tincidunt. Donec consectetur sem vitae lorem finibus dictum. Pellentesque cursus sollicitudin eros vitae ullamcorper. Praesent consectetur posuere metus vel dictum. Mauris vitae fringilla libero. Fusce dui leo, bibendum a porttitor ullamcorper, scelerisque vitae quam. Praesent laoreet magna nisi, sit amet luctus quam condimentum vel. Phasellus aliquam nec sem sed eleifend. Donec hendrerit semper efficitur. Sed malesuada nisi quis arcu accumsan tincidunt. Mauris rutrum nisl lorem, a ullamcorper massa pharetra at. Pellentesque et risus sit amet massa finibus consequat eget vitae nibh.</p>

  
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut varius sagittis tincidunt. Donec consectetur sem vitae lorem finibus dictum. Pellentesque cursus sollicitudin eros vitae ullamcorper. Praesent consectetur posuere metus vel dictum. Mauris vitae fringilla libero. Fusce dui leo, bibendum a porttitor ullamcorper, scelerisque vitae quam. Praesent laoreet magna nisi, sit amet luctus quam condimentum vel. Phasellus aliquam nec sem sed eleifend. Donec hendrerit semper efficitur. Sed malesuada nisi quis arcu accumsan tincidunt. Mauris rutrum nisl lorem, a ullamcorper massa pharetra at. Pellentesque et risus sit amet massa finibus consequat eget vitae nibh.</p>

  
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut varius sagittis tincidunt. Donec consectetur sem vitae lorem finibus dictum. Pellentesque cursus sollicitudin eros vitae ullamcorper. Praesent consectetur posuere metus vel dictum. Mauris vitae fringilla libero. Fusce dui leo, bibendum a porttitor ullamcorper, scelerisque vitae quam. Praesent laoreet magna nisi, sit amet luctus quam condimentum vel. Phasellus aliquam nec sem sed eleifend. Donec hendrerit semper efficitur. Sed malesuada nisi quis arcu accumsan tincidunt. Mauris rutrum nisl lorem, a ullamcorper massa pharetra at. Pellentesque et risus sit amet massa finibus consequat eget vitae nibh.</p>

  
  
<div id="foo">
  <a href="">aaa</a>
</div>


<div id="fooo">
      <a href="">bbb</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, the first thing you need to do is use ASP.NET MVC. The Code Snippet feature is for HTML/JS/CSS, not ASP.NET.

Comment: action link generate only `<a>` tag. use `@Url.Action()` helper go get href if you need it on `div`.

Comment: Firstly, the asp.net mvc genereate the code into html and then you use css code. How should I retrieve a link that is generated in asp.net mvc and use it in the picture. In other words, the connection between actionlink and the css's url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
p {
    font-size: 24px;
}

#foo {
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    display:block;
    top:400px;
    width:128px;
    height:128px;
    background: #f00 url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/uiconstock/50-free-christmas/128/candy-2-icon.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
  
  

}

#fooo {
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    display:block;
    top:400px;
    width:128px;
    height:128px;
    background: #f00 url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/uiconstock/50-free-christmas/128/candy-2-icon.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
  

}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut varius sagittis tincidunt. Donec consectetur sem vitae lorem finibus dictum. Pellentesque cursus sollicitudin eros vitae ullamcorper. Praesent consectetur posuere metus vel dictum. Mauris vitae fringilla libero. Fusce dui leo, bibendum a porttitor ullamcorper, scelerisque vitae quam. Praesent laoreet magna nisi, sit amet luctus quam condimentum vel. Phasellus aliquam nec sem sed eleifend. Donec hendrerit semper efficitur. Sed malesuada nisi quis arcu accumsan tincidunt. Mauris rutrum nisl lorem, a ullamcorper massa pharetra at. Pellentesque et risus sit amet massa finibus consequat eget vitae nibh.</p>

<p>Ut dapibus aliquet imperdiet. Maecenas gravida sagittis eros, nec vestibulum lacus sagittis at. Nulla enim dui, ultricies a quam id, placerat placerat erat. Donec pretium orci purus, eget tristique neque mattis eget. Nullam mattis accumsan urna et faucibus. Praesent tincidunt lobortis tortor, maximus tincidunt neque cursus luctus. Sed in rutrum lacus. Nunc volutpat fringilla diam. Curabitur accumsan, est sed mattis ultricies, augue quam suscipit nisi, sit amet lobortis erat lorem in nunc. Nullam sagittis vulputate placerat. Nullam fringilla arcu id purus pretium, sed fringilla ligula aliquam.</p>

<p>Morbi quis mauris condimentum, accumsan nunc ac, porttitor nibh. Pellentesque maximus dolor nisi, eget bibendum nibh feugiat mollis. Donec lacinia turpis vulputate, viverra sapien in, aliquam metus. Etiam posuere, urna at dapibus placerat, lacus dolor imperdiet lorem, sit amet efficitur ante dui efficitur est. Cras quis tincidunt sapien. Fusce sit amet ultricies mauris. Mauris sit amet faucibus velit. Pellentesque non leo ante.</p>

<p>Sed eget lacus sodales, porttitor justo non, ornare magna. Phasellus pulvinar porta eros eget ultricies. Aliquam ante lectus, ultricies vel iaculis nec, posuere quis sapien. Praesent nisi purus, fermentum nec tortor sagittis, efficitur consectetur ipsum. Vivamus condimentum velit sed dictum fringilla. Mauris eu vulputate neque, eu ornare justo. Ut iaculis et libero nec lobortis. Quisque euismod quam felis, sed imperdiet enim feugiat fermentum. In viverra turpis molestie luctus elementum. Vestibulum quis vulputate massa. Praesent convallis congue dolor nec ornare. Aliquam lobortis est vitae lorem tempor viverra.</p>

<p>Duis commodo congue porttitor. Aenean nunc arcu, ultricies semper cursus a, euismod eget orci. Etiam tempus aliquam nisl non tristique. Fusce lobortis sagittis enim, id mattis magna semper congue. Nulla ornare venenatis ante, hendrerit sagittis dolor ultricies nec. Praesent varius sit amet odio quis lobortis. Praesent quis egestas sem, eget dignissim felis. Pellentesque risus enim, viverra a blandit in, laoreet sed quam. Duis et congue risus, sed consequat massa. Nunc non pharetra tortor. Morbi elementum magna vitae rutrum pulvinar. Donec sit amet leo arcu.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut varius sagittis tincidunt. Donec consectetur sem vitae lorem finibus dictum. Pellentesque cursus sollicitudin eros vitae ullamcorper. Praesent consectetur posuere metus vel dictum. Mauris vitae fringilla libero. Fusce dui leo, bibendum a porttitor ullamcorper, scelerisque vitae quam. Praesent laoreet magna nisi, sit amet luctus quam condimentum vel. Phasellus aliquam nec sem sed eleifend. Donec hendrerit semper efficitur. Sed malesuada nisi quis arcu accumsan tincidunt. Mauris rutrum nisl lorem, a ullamcorper massa pharetra at. Pellentesque et risus sit amet massa finibus consequat eget vitae nibh.</p>

  
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut varius sagittis tincidunt. Donec consectetur sem vitae lorem finibus dictum. Pellentesque cursus sollicitudin eros vitae ullamcorper. Praesent consectetur posuere metus vel dictum. Mauris vitae fringilla libero. Fusce dui leo, bibendum a porttitor ullamcorper, scelerisque vitae quam. Praesent laoreet magna nisi, sit amet luctus quam condimentum vel. Phasellus aliquam nec sem sed eleifend. Donec hendrerit semper efficitur. Sed malesuada nisi quis arcu accumsan tincidunt. Mauris rutrum nisl lorem, a ullamcorper massa pharetra at. Pellentesque et risus sit amet massa finibus consequat eget vitae nibh.</p>

  
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut varius sagittis tincidunt. Donec consectetur sem vitae lorem finibus dictum. Pellentesque cursus sollicitudin eros vitae ullamcorper. Praesent consectetur posuere metus vel dictum. Mauris vitae fringilla libero. Fusce dui leo, bibendum a porttitor ullamcorper, scelerisque vitae quam. Praesent laoreet magna nisi, sit amet luctus quam condimentum vel. Phasellus aliquam nec sem sed eleifend. Donec hendrerit semper efficitur. Sed malesuada nisi quis arcu accumsan tincidunt. Mauris rutrum nisl lorem, a ullamcorper massa pharetra at. Pellentesque et risus sit amet massa finibus consequat eget vitae nibh.</p>

  
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut varius sagittis tincidunt. Donec consectetur sem vitae lorem finibus dictum. Pellentesque cursus sollicitudin eros vitae ullamcorper. Praesent consectetur posuere metus vel dictum. Mauris vitae fringilla libero. Fusce dui leo, bibendum a porttitor ullamcorper, scelerisque vitae quam. Praesent laoreet magna nisi, sit amet luctus quam condimentum vel. Phasellus aliquam nec sem sed eleifend. Donec hendrerit semper efficitur. Sed malesuada nisi quis arcu accumsan tincidunt. Mauris rutrum nisl lorem, a ullamcorper massa pharetra at. Pellentesque et risus sit amet massa finibus consequat eget vitae nibh.</p>

  
  
<a href="#" id="foo">
  <span>aaa</span>
</a>


<a href="" id="fooo">
      <span>bbb</span>
</a>
```

You would need to use Url.Action to get the URL corresponding to the relevant action. The following code snippet would map to the "Foo" and "Fooo" actions of your controller.

```
<a id="foo" href='@Url.Action("Foo", "ControllerName")'>
  <span>aaa</span>
</a>


<a href='@Url.Action("Fooo","ControllerName")' id="fooo">
  <span>bbb</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Please remember that it is the candy picture should be the link, not the text.

Comment: Don' understand your message. Please tell me what you mean?

Comment: I've updated the markup to use an anchor instead of a div and wrapped the text with a span. (See my update and the snippet).

Comment: Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 0):

seeing the containing div is position fixed, you can make the a tag absolute and define left, right, top and bottom...

```
#foo a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-indent: -99999px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet that's the shortest way. But i really don't like inline js...

Still:

```
<div 
onclick="javascript:window.location.href='@Url.Action("Foo", "ControllerName")'; 
return false;" 
id="foo">
</div>
```

Also it's better to add `div { cursor: pointer; }` to your css, if you want to show that's the href.